# How to view all components of a scrollview

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I have a scrollview with a lot of components in the layout that there is inside it. The result is like that:

[image: Scrollview]

I want to know if is there a way to view all components in Android Studio because I need to make changes in the design and currently, by this way it is so difficult.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `android:scrollY` property on the ScrollView, say 50dp in the beginning and then keep on increasing as you move further down. Make sure you remove this property before production ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add a new device definition,
Setting it with a bigger height,
And using that one in your preview ?

I've just give it a try and it works nicely !

[image: from_ide]

[image: avd]

Answer (score 0):

You should set gone property with for view on top of layout, so you can see view below to edit it. 
Let fun with android studio preview!